# Sinatra (rack.session) session auth

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, padrino

I have a Padrino application. And I would like to share the session between instances (load balanced machines).

I set my own secret, but I don't know what else to set to let it work for session sharing. I see domain in cookie, where is hostname of the machine. I tried to set it by

```
set :sessions, :domain => 'mydomain.org'
```

But it is not working, but it is necessary? Please, what I have to set to share the session between application instances.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put the cookie info into an environment variable that is run every time Sinatra runs a new instance of the app, e.g.

```
require 'securerandom'
require 'encrypted_cookie'

COOKIE_SETTINGS = {
  :path => "/",
  :expire_after => 86400 * 60, # In seconds, 60 days
  :secret => ENV["SESSION_SECRET"] || SecureRandom.hex(64),
  :httponly => true
}

configure do
  cookie_settings = COOKIE_SETTINGS
  cookie_settings.merge!( :secure => true ) if settings.production?
  use Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie, cookie_settings
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to share between two different applications? A little unclear with your question.

Sharing session between two entirely different applications is a security issue.

Here's a possible solution to what I think your problem may be.

```
  use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'my_app_key',
                             :path => '/',
                             :expire_after => 14400, # In seconds
                             :secret => 'secret_stuff'
```

Do you see the difference from the above? - No Domain, if I let Rack::Session::Cookie specify the domain or the browser (whoever does it), I have no errors between mutliple Sinatra/Rack apps.